# How do I read a data file with spaces in the row names into python?

Tags: python-3.x

In python I want to create a dictionary from a text file with two "columns". The first column contains names sometimes separated by spaces. The second column contains floats. Both columns are centered in the data file (why?). I don't know how to pythonically deal with the spaces. I am looking for a solution that I can use to iterate through many of these files.

What I see in the text file:

> ```
>            value err     0.123
>                 value    3.000
> ```

What the output from csv reader looks like:

```
with open('text.data') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

> []
>
> ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
> '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'value', 'err', '', '', '',
> '', '', '', '', '0.123']
>
> ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
> '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
> '', '', 'value', '', '', '', '3.00']

What I want it to look like:

> ['value_err', 0.123]
>
> ['value', 3.00]

Comment: Can you change the data format? This really seems ill defined.
The first step would be to strip away whitespace from the border, but you probably need to use regex, e.g. `r"\s*(.+?)\s+([\d.]+)"`.

Comment: Have you checked if data files use the TAB character as the real delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's only two columns, and the second shouldn't contain any internal spaces, this should work:

```
with open('text.data') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        print(['_'.join(line[:-1]), float(line[-1])])
```

There's a number of things that could break this (additional columns, multiple internal spaces, blank lines, etc.), but absent a more complete definition of the file format, we have to make some guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
with open('text.data') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    formatted_row = [x for x in row if x != '']
```

Now, in the question your csv file has `value err` as a value. This is kind of odd since it is two words. It is a typo in your question ?

Basically, my solution will strip any spaces in what you read.

Comment: Not a typo, some of the names are two words.